# Multiple buttons with same width equal to widest button

Tags: blackberry

I have multiple ButtonFields in a VerticalFieldManager.  By default the width of each button depends on the text it contains.

I would like all the buttons to be of the same width - equal to the width of the widest button.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the BlackBerry Developers Knowledge Base:
[How to - Implement advanced buttons, fields, and managers](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0)
Last Updated: 12 February 2010
Article Number: DB-00796

You are probably looking for the VerticalButtonFieldSet!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Extend the VerticalFieldManager class, and make the constructor take in a bunch of Strings that you want to put end each button.

Step 2 - Find the longest of String out of the Strings passed into the manager.

Step 3 - create the button for the longest string

Step 4 - create all other buttons, and set their width to the same as the 1st (see setExtent)

Step 5 - add the buttons to the manager in the order you want them to appear

FIN

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH` style flag?

Try `ButtonField buttonField = new ButtonField("ButtonText", Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);`

and that should use the full width.

If that doesn't work, try extending ButtonField, overriding layout and calling `setExtent(width, height)` with the width and height that you want.